# How to covert JSON data into an array to plot a chart?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've a php query which creates the JSON data of the the data received from the SQL query that is run. The JSON data is created using this query using this query

```
echo json_encode($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Now I want to plot a chart using fusionchart for which I need to convert this data into an array. I tried a sample JS code to convert the JSON data into an JS array and it worked

```
var data = { "timestamp": "2016-09-23", "value1": "0", "value2": "0", ........., "value49": "0", "value50": "0" };
   var arr = [];
   for (elem in data) {
        arr.push(data[elem]);
    }
    console.log(arr);
```

Now in the **data** variable I need to pass the data from php code. This is just one of the records that I entered manually. There are over a million records and I need to convert all of them. How I do this?

Comment: 'There are over a million records' - not sure if that's going to work well anyway.

Comment: Already tried JSON_Decode. It did not work.

Comment: @nigelren Still I need to try to do it. Its a mandatory requirement.

Comment: Do you want to plot all the records at once or is there some sort of constraint?

Comment: _"I need to pass the data from php code"_ - Where exactly are you stuck? Does the json-data you got from PHP look correct? Are you using Ajax or are you fetching the data on page load?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. First, why dont you try a structure like `var data = {timestamp: "2016-09-23", values: [0, 0, ... 0, 0]}` so all you have to do is something like `data.resultsFromPHP = JSON.parse(receivedFromPHP);` ? Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @magnuseriksson I'm fetching the data on page load. The JSON data is correct but, I'm unable to convert the entire data in JSON at once. Passing the **$res** variable in JS doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew Yes there are certain constraints to plot the chart.

Comment: @Zyigh I could try this structure. The structure that I've given is the default structure created by `json_encode`. I'm uanle to pass the `$res` variable in the JS.

Comment: @Will I'm really not sure I really understand what you want to do... I hope I won't be ridiculous... Why don't y ou try the maner you fetch data in your PHP code ? Isn't a fetch_lazy appropriate for what you want to do ?

Comment: Try and fix the data structure in PHP before you encode it? Then you can also cache it for future requests so you don't need to restructure the data on each request.

Comment: Regarding _"I'm unable to pass the $res variable directly to the data variable"_, of course not. `$res` is a result set, not an array. You need to store the result in a variable. Instead of `echo json_encode($res->...)`, do `$data = json_encode($res->..)`. Then you can echo the `$data` variable where ever you want.

Comment: Just to keep going with @NigelRen note, maybe you should pass a bit less than 1 million value at once. I don't know what you hope to do with that but I can't imagine a situation where anyone need 1 million informations at once

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Object.values()` function to acquire values from an object.

```js
var data = { "timestamp": "2016-09-23", "value1": "0", "value2": "0", "value49": "0", "value50": "0" };

var arr = Object.values(data);
console.log(arr);
```

For PHP

You can send only values and omit keys in `PHP` using following code. `json_decode` converts `JSON` string to an array. `implode` converts an array to a string.

```
<?php

$str = '{ "timestamp": "2016-09-23", "value1": "val1", 
        "value2": "val2", "value49": "val49", "value50": "val50" }';
$myJSON = json_decode($str, true);

echo '[' . implode(",", $myJSON) . ']';
```

Results:

> [2016-09-23,val1,val2,val49,val50]

Comment: The problem that I'm facing is not that I cannot convert it into JS array, I'm unable to pass the `$res` variable directly to the data variable, so that it can convert the entire dataset into JS array at once.

Comment: @Will I changed my solution to answer back-end requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseJSON()` function :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: The problem that I'm facing is not that I cannot convert it into JS array, I'm unable to pass the $res variable directly to the data variable, so that it can convert the entire dataset into JS array at once.